# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nativeElement')

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-test

So I want to access this "save" button which is inside-
Format

```
<ng-container>
 <div></div>

 <div *ngIf="condition">
    <div class="className">
      <div>
        <button nz-button class="m-r-10" [nzType]="'success'" 
          [disabled]="!dataSubmittedFlag"
          (click)="attemptForTransaction('submit')">Submit
        </button>
        <button nz-button class="m-r-10" [nzType]="'primary'" 
          [disabled]="!dataSubmittedFlag"
          (click)="attemptForTransaction('save')">Save
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Here I try to access the text content of the save button and it gives me the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'nativeElement')"

Also when I console log the length of the 'buttonDebugElements', it shows the length is 0 (when it should read 2) meaning no button is being read.

spec.ts

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';

import { NgZorroAntdModule } from 'app/ng-zorro.module';
import { TransactionDetailsComponent } from './transaction-details.component';


describe('TransactionDetailsComponent', () => {
 let component: TransactionDetailsComponent;
 let fixture: ComponentFixture<TransactionDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ TransactionDetailsComponent ],
      providers:[{}
      ],
      imports:[NgZorroAntdModule,RouterTestingModule,ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TransactionDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
  it('should check if save button is clickable',()=>{
    const buttonDebugElements = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('button'));

    const secondButtonDebugElement = buttonDebugElements[1];

    const buttonTextContent = secondButtonDebugElement.nativeElement.textContent;
    expect(buttonTextContent).toBe('Save');
  })
});
```

Is there any fix for this issue?

Comment: is your `condition` true ?

Comment: yes and I can confirm this because the button is rendered on UI and is visible.

Comment: You can see the button rendered but the test could fail anyway if the condition is triggered asynchronously. In your place, I would remove the condition to check that it isn't an issue. It's hard to say if we cant see components internals

Comment: I thought there was a fix without changing any of the component code.